# Trying to install cantos7

Tags: centos

This time when I boot from USB (either "regular" boot or UEFI boot) the installer get's stuck a while at
[ok] Reached target Basic System.

After a couple of minutes it shows:

> ```
> > dracut-initqueue[642]: Warning: could not boot. [ok] Started sShow
> > Plymouth Boot Screen. [ok] Reached target Paths. [ok] Reached target
> > Basic System. dracut-initqueue[642]: Warning: Could not boot.
> > dracut-initqueue[642]: Warning: /dev/root does not exist Starting
> > Dracut Emergency Shell
> > 
> > Warning: /dev/root does not exist
> > 
> > Generating "/run/iniramfs/rdsosreport.txt"
> > 
> > Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
> ```

Now what? I don't understand why I'm experiencing so much trouble, nor why the installer is so little helpful.
I'm really starting to wonder if CentOS is the way to go?